# What is wrong with my Phoenix lambda expression?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

I would expect the following example Boost Phoenix expression to compile.

What am I missing?

```
int plus(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

void main(int argc,char** argc)
{
    auto plus_1 = phx::bind(&plus,1,arg1);
    auto value  = phx::lambda[phx::val(plus_1)(arg1)]()(1);
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
auto plus_1 = phx::bind(&plus,1,arg1);
```

After this line, `plus_1` is a function object that takes one `int` argument and adds one to it.

```
phx::lambda[plus_1(arg1)](1);
```

Whoops. This isn't going to work because (as we said above) `plus_1` is a function object that takes one `int` argument and adds one to it. Here, you're trying to invoke it with `arg1`.

It isn't obvious from your code what you expect it to do. Can you clarify?

**====EDIT====**

I see you've edited the code in your question. Your code is still wrong but for a different reason now. This:

```
phx::val(plus_1)(arg1)
```

... uses `val` to create a nullary function that returns the `plus_1` unary function. You then try to invoke the nullary function with `arg1`. Boom.

Here is code that executes and does (what I believe) you intend:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/phoenix/phoenix.hpp>
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
using phx::arg_names::arg1;

int plus(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int main()
{
    auto plus_1 = phx::bind(&plus, 1, arg1);
    int value = phx::bind(phx::lambda[plus_1], arg1)(1);
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

The first `bind` takes the binary `plus` and turns it into a unary function with the first argument bound to `1`. The second `bind` creates a new unary function that is *equivalent to the first*, but it does so by safely wrapping the first function using `lambda`. Why is that necessary? Consider the code below, which is equivalent, but without the `lambda`:

```
// Oops, wrong:
int value = phx::bind(phx::bind(&plus, 1, arg1), arg1)(1);
```

Notice that `arg1` appears twice. All expressions get evaluated from the inside out. First, we'll bind the inner `arg1` to `1`, then evaluate the inner `bind` yielding `2`, which we then try to bind and invoke. That's not going to work because `2` isn't callable.

The use of `lambda` creates a scope for the inner `arg1` so it isn't eagerly substituted. But like I said, the use of the second `bind`, which forces the need for `lambda`, yields a function that is equivalent to the first. So it's needlessly complicated. But maybe it helped you understand about `bind`, `lambda` and Phoenix scopes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. My intent to to understand Phoenix better. I find bind to be confusing based on the documentation.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you need to wrap the lambda with a bind expression. What is preventing the lambda from living on it's own. Is it because a PHX expression is really a lambda? Thanks a again for the answer.

Comment: Ok I think i get it. Basically function object are not Actors and bind  does not return and Actor but a function object.The lambda it needed to wrap the function object with and Actor for it to be lazy evaluated.

Comment: No, `bind` expressions return Actors. Actors _are_ function objects. You don't need to wrap the `lambda` in a `bind`. You can do this, for instance: `int value = phx::lambda[plus_1]()(1)`. `lambda` is like a level of indirection; evaluate it once to get the body of the lambda, then evaluate it again to get the final result.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish by using `lambda` here, but if you just want to call `plus_1` with `1` (resulting in `2`), it's much simpler than your attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

int plus(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

    auto plus_1 = phx::bind(plus, 1, phx::arg_names::arg1);
    std::cout << plus_1(1) << '\n';
}
```

<sup>[Online demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/de99a99396a4d6a3e52010d36cbdcc9d)</sup>

If this *isn't* what you're trying to accomplish, then you need to describe what you actually want. :-]

Comment: I would expect my expression to work. It's not that I am trying accomplish adding numbers but understand why lamba does not do what I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can explain it better.

Phoenix is not *magic*; it is first and foremost C++. It therefore follows the *rules* of C++.

`phx::bind` is a function that returns a function object, an object which has an overloaded `operator()` that calls the function that was bound. Your first statement stores this object into `plus_1`.

Given all of this, ***anytime*** you have the expression `plus_1(...)`, this is a *function call*. That's what it is; you are saying that you want to call the overloaded `operator()` function on the type of that object, and that you are going to pass some values to that function.

It doesn't matter whether that expression is in the middle of a `[]` or not. `phx::lambda` cannot make C++ change its rules. It can't make `plus_1(...)` anything *other* than an immediate function call. Nor can `arg1` make `plus_1(...)` not an immediate function call.